# Parse diverse array of numbers for value and number

Tags: php

I am using `PHP 7.3.5` and I have the following set of array values:

```
$valueArr = ['-4.2%', '51.0', '90K', '0.5%', '0.74|2.6', '-1.2B', '779B', '215K', '92.2%', '42.8B', '1.49T', '1690B', '-10.8B', '0.38|3.9', '102.4', '1.00%', '0.07|1.3'];
```

Basically I want for each of these values the number and the "type", so if it is a percentage then I would like to get `-4.2` and `percentage`.

I tried to create a minimum example (however the below code is no real good example ;( ), but I am stuck at the data structure level as some array keys have two inputs, such as `'0.74|2.6'`:

```
<?php


$valueArr = ['-4.2%', '51.0', '90K', '0.5%', '0.74|2.6', '-1.2B', '779B', '215K', '92.2%', '42.8B', '1.49T', '1690B', '-10.8B', '0.38|3.9', '102.4', '1.00%', '0.07|1.3'];

$resArr = array();
$structureArr = array(
    'value1' => "",
    'number1' => "",
    'value2' => "",
    'number2' => ""
);
foreach ($valueArr as $key => $v) {
    if (1 === preg_match('/%/', $valueArr[$key])) {
        preg_match('!\d+\.*\d*!', $valueArr[$key], $structureArr['number1']);
        $structureArr['value1'] = 'percentage';
    }
    /*
    if (1 === preg_match('|', $valueArr[$key])) {
        $str = explode("|", $valueArr[$key]);
        $value1 = 'number';
        $number1 = $str[0];
        $value2 = 'number';
        $number2 = $str[1];
    }
    if (1 === preg_match('', $valueArr[$key])) {

    }
    */
    array_push($resArr, $structureArr);
}

print_r($resArr);
/*
Wanted Result
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => -4.2
            [1] => 'percentage'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 51.0
            [1] => 'number'
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 90000
            [1] => number
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.5
            [1] => percentage
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.74
            [1] => number
            [2] => 2.6
            [3] => number
        )

   ...
*/
```

I would highly appreciate your input on how to structure this array input.

Appreciate your replies!

Comment: So the options for "type" are just percentage and number?

Comment: Yea so `B` is number or `Bytes` or something etc...???

Comment: @AbraCadaver  I was thinking K = thousand, B = billion, M = million, T = trillion, etc

Comment: @Patrick Exactly

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes exactly: `K = thousand, B = billion, M = million, T = trillion`

Comment: Create array mapping suffix to multiplier.  Loop through array, explode on `|`, if last character is `%`, strip it, value=value and type=percentage, else, strip last char, use it as array index, value=value*multiplier and type=number.

Comment: @Anna.Klee  I'm curious why you marked Abra's answer as the accepted one when it doesn't actually produce the result that you asked for.  I like how clean it is, but when it comes down to it, it doesn't solve the problem as stated.

Comment: @PatrickQ Thx for asking. I rethought about your answer and it is much clearer  and accepted your answer!

Comment: @Anna.Klee  Okay.  I couldn't care less about the "points", but I wanted to make sure there wasn't something I misunderstood about what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expands on my comment.  Not sure if it's the most optimal solution or not.

Rough outline...

Create array mapping suffix to multiplier. Loop through source array. explode on `|`. Loop through result. If last character is %, strip it, value=value and type=percentage, else, strip last char, use it as array index (if it is an available index), value=value*multiplier and type=number.

```
$resArr = array();

$multipliers = array("K" => 1000, "M" => 1000000, "B" => 1000000000, "T" => 1000000000000);

$valueArr = ['-4.2%', '51.0', '90K', '0.5%', '0.74|2.6', '-1.2B', '779B', '215K', '92.2%', '42.8B', '1.49T', '1690B', '-10.8B', '0.38|3.9', '102.4', '1.00%', '0.07|1.3'];

foreach($valueArr as $index => $value)
{
    $parts = explode("|", $value);

    $resArr[$index] = array();

    foreach($parts as $part)
    {
        $lastChar = substr($part, -1);

        if($lastChar == "%")
        {
            $resArr[$index][] = substr($part, 0, -1);
            $resArr[$index][] = "percentage";
        }
        else if(in_array($lastChar, array_keys($multipliers)))
        {
            $multiple = $multipliers[$lastChar];
            $resArr[$index][] = (substr($part, 0, -1))*$multiple;
            $resArr[$index][] = "number";
        }
        else
        {
            $resArr[$index][] = $part;
            $resArr[$index][] = "number";
        }
    }
}

var_dump($resArr);
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3b012c1c063fa25c2c21a165576b26efd54f389c)

Answer (score 2):

If you join the array on a space and replace pipes `|` with a space, then you have a list of numbers and their symbol (if any) separated by a space. Then just match your numbers and whatever symbol comes after it.  Then you just match the number index with the symbol index.  I used an array to map the symbol to the word and `number` if none:

```
$string = str_replace('|', ' ', implode(' ', $valueArr));
preg_match_all('/([\d.-]+)([^\s]*)/', $string, $matches);
$types = ['%'=>'percent','K'=>'thousand','M'=>'million','B'=>'billion','T'=>'trillion'];

foreach($matches[1] as $k => $v) {
    $t = $types[$matches[2][$k]] ?? 'number';
    $result[] = [$v, $t];
}
```

This yields an array like this, with each number that was joined by a pipe with it's own element:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => -4.2
            [1] => percent
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 51.0
            [1] => number
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 90
            [1] => thousand
        )

    ///etc...
```

If you need a floating point number then just change:

```
    $result[] = [(float)$v, $t];
```

Comment: Maybe move the `$types` outside the `foreach` to not reassign it on every iteration.

Comment: @ChinLeung: Thanks, was typing and not thinking